# setup of xamarin studio to work with PCL & MVVMCross

Tags: ide, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I really enjoy Xamarin Studio and I'm looking for a template solution to start developing a cross devices application with MvvmCross.

But I can't find how to set a project to work with PCL and MvvmCross with Xamarin Studio.

If anyone can give me a link where I can find a tutorial to make it, it would be awesome.

I would be very pleased to contribute to this community by giving my feedback and providing some tutorial about how to start using Xamarin Studio, PCL MvvmCross and get rid of Visual Studio :D

Comment: Give me a couple of hours... just updating the presentation templates for v3 from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Templates (as well as 20 other jobs)

Comment: You may work 20hours a day :O fortunately, a day is composed of 24 hours :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @duDE's answer pointed out, for working in Visual Studio on the PC in the pre-Xamarin2.0 world, there were quite detailed instructions available on http://slodge.blogspot.de/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html

As various releases of Xamarin 2.0 have been released over the last month, these type of instructions have become more and more difficult to keep up to date... and this situation is likely to continue for a little while yet as Xamarin are currently adding:

- .Net 4.5 (Mono 3) support
- async/await support
- PCL support

This work is being done with some urgency, but without any official target date - so I'm afraid there isn't any easy way to predict dates for Alpha, Beta or final availability.

---

For the current OSX setup, I think you can use:

- the current XamarinStudio/MonoDevelop - 4.0.2
- the current **stable** Xamarin.iOS/MonoTouch and Xamarin.Android/MonoDroid - do **not** use the *Aplha* channel

For the current PC setup, I think you can **cannot** use Xamarin.iOS, but you **can** use:

- VS2010 or VS2012
- the current **stable** Xamarin.Android/MonoDroid - do **not** use the *Aplha* channel
- with just a couple of changes:

  - you need to add two supported framework xml files - one for Android and one for MonoTouch - you can find these on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/xamarinios-with-mvvmcross-in-vs2012.html

---

For discussions on getting things building and running, don't use StackOverflow - instead use one of:

- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1549/pcls-and-mvvmcross-in-the-new-tools#latest

as a backup you can also try https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/mvvmcross

---

Don't even think about trying to get an MvvmCross app built - on the free version of Xamarin - it's limits are way too low for any app I've tried to build.

---

If you are looking for some starting app templates, use: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Templates

If you are looking for some pre-built binaries, use one one of the folders on: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries - please note that portable libraries built on the Mac are not portable across to the PC (or vice versa) - they will be 'soon' but not yet.

---

Sorry for the fact that we don't have a neater, finished solution... we've now been fighting to hack PCLs into Xamarin for a year. However, the good news is that really soon that battle will be over and we can all get on with the apps :)

---

I guarantee this answer is out of date inside a week...

Comment: Woaw ! Thank you a lot for your answer Stuart. I really appreciate what you done with MvvmCross. It has been a very long time since i didnt fall in love for a framework (last time was on the release of Silverlight 2). And then i saw MvvmCross and started my first application <3 :)

It's ok if i just have to wait a couple of week or even mounth. I'm not in a hurry. I knew that xamarin was working on async/await and 4.5 but i didnt know how PCL was going. I'll add a comment after reading all the stuff you linked to me.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Studio 4.2 allows you to create PCL projects.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://slodge.blogspot.de/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html

Many information about using PCLs as well as some special infos about MVVMCross

Comment: Thank you for this link. I didnt find this post while i was looking for more details. Do you know if everything mentioned in the article linked work too with xamarin Studio ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know it, I'm on evaluating of Xamarin as well.

Comment: Ok don't be sorry you don't have to. It's very cool that you answer so fast. I'm evaluating Xamarin too but since Stuart answered me, i think i ll wait mono 4.5 and PCL to evaluate Xamarin deeper. Have a good day duDE