# Xamarin.Forms app will not run on Android device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

Just created a Xamarin.Forms app in Xamarin Studio 5.2.1 using the Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) template.

Made no code changes, built solution, attempted to run it on a connected Android device via right-click on my .Android project and choosing Run With.

Instead of deploying and starting the app, I get an error "Execution failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Has anyone run into this and figured out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21508 and inferred that no startup project set for the solution could be the cause of the exception.

Set my .Android project as startup project and all is well.